# Advice needed with grabbing names and numbers from a txt file

Tags: c

I am writing a program that grabs names and numbers from a txt and adds them to an array depending if its a string or number.

My current program is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE * ifp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE * ofp = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
    int participants = 0, i , j;
    char name [10];
    int grade [26];

    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &participants);

    for (i = 1; i < participants; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", name);          
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &grade[j]);  
        }
    }

    printf( "%d\n", participants);
    printf( "%s\n", name);
    printf( "%d\n", grade);

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);

    return 0;
}
```

My output is this:

```
2
Optimus
2686616
```

My txt file is this:

```
2 
Optimus 
45 90 
30 60 
25 30 
50 70 
Megatron 
5 6 
7 9 
3 4 
8 10
```

Any ideas on how I make it so it displays like this instead:

```
2 
Optimus 
Megatron 
45 
90 
30 
60 
25 
30 
50 
70 
5 
6 
7 
9 
3 
4 
8 
10
```

Comment: If the data has a specific structure consider using a format that is able to catch that. - Also in that case please provide the structure of the input in your question, to avoid guessing. For instance is the first number 2, the number of entries?

Comment: I just need to find a way to get the numbers into the array. Once I can figure that out I can continue. I just hit a roadblock.

Comment: Just create an array and load the numbers into it?

Comment: I have to read the numbers in from the file, which is why I tried:

fscanf(ifp, "%s", name) and fscanf(ifp, "%d", &grade[j])

Comment: Well I would go with `strtok` and `atoi` but the result should be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the data in the requested format, you would require a 2D array to store your values. Since the number of participants is not known apriori, you would have to dynamically allocate the required space and free it up later. Please find a reworked version of your code as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    FILE * ifp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE * ofp = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
    int participants = 0, i , j;
    char **name; // Changed the name to a 2D array
    int **grade; // Changed the grade to a 2D array
    char *curname; // Temp pointer to current name
    int  *curgrade; // Temp pointer to current array of grades



    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &participants);

    // Allocate memory
    name = malloc((sizeof(char *) * participants)); // Allocate pointers to hold strings for the number of participants
    grade = malloc((sizeof(int *) * participants)); // Allocate pointers to hold grades for the number of participants

    for(i = 0; i < participants; i++) {
        name[i] = malloc((sizeof(char) * 10)); //Assumption: Name doesn't exceed 10 characters
        grade[i] = malloc((sizeof(int) * 8)); // Assumption: Only 8 grades
   }

    for (i = 0; i < participants; i++) { /* Fixed: index i should start from 0 */
        curname = name[i]; // Get pointer to current name
        curgrade = &grade[i][0]; // Get pointer to array of current grades
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", curname); // Read name into current name pointer
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", &curgrade[j]); // Read grades into current array
        }
    }


    printf("%d\n", participants);
    for(i = 0; i < participants; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", name[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < participants; i++) {
        curgrade = &grade[i][0];
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", curgrade[j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);

    for(i = 0; i < participants; i++) {
        free(name[i]); // Free the array of individual names
        free(grade[i]); // Free the array of grades for every participant
    }

    free(grade); // Free the grades pointer
    free(name); // Free the names pointer

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok` to generate tokens from the file, splitting on newline and space, then check if each string is a number, by trying to parse it, using `itoa` or something alike that, if parseable add to numbers otherwise to names.

Comment: It looks like they know what the input format will be, they're just having trouble with outputting it correctly (and saving the data)